# Problems getting response

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm having some troubles trying to execute an ajax call. It is stored in chat.js (added in the html head) and it does a call to getChatHistory.php

**chat.js:**

```
function getChatHistory(user1, user2){  
var response = 'fail';
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
        response = response + xmlhttp.responseText;
    } else {
        response = "Error:" + hmlhttp.status;
    }

    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'getChatHistory.php?user1=' + user1 + '&user2=' + user2);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
return response;}
```

**getChatHistory.php:**

```
<?php
echo "the php talks";
?>
```

**index.html:**

```
<script>
(function(){
  alert(getChatHistory('user1', 'user2');
})()
```

I checked with `alert()` and the `onreadystatechange` event doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? it isn't firing? Open your console and check for errors

Comment: One problem is that you have '`hmlhttp.status`' instead of '`xmlhttp.status`'

Comment: Seems there is a closing ")" missing in the alert command in index.html?

Comment: You are both correct. I wrote it manually but i dont have those errors in the files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not sending the request due to the fact that your .open and .send functions are inside of your callback, try this instead:

```
function getChatHistory(user1, user2){  
    var response = 'fail';
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            response = response + xmlhttp.responseText;
        } else {
            response = "Error:" + hmlhttp.status;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'getChatHistory.php?user1=' + user1 + '&user2=' + user2);
    xmlhttp.send();
    return response;
}
```

Note, that you are also going to run into issues getting the `response` to return due to the fact that it's an async request. The response will return undefined unless you either a) make it a synchronous request (generally a bad idea) or b) set your action requiring the response to fire after the ready state has completed. Here is a basic example of how you could do so:

```
function getChatHistory(user1, user2, onComplete){  
    var response = 'fail';
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            response = response + xmlhttp.responseText;
        } else {
            response = "Error:" + hmlhttp.status;
        }

        onComplete(response);
    }

    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'getChatHistory.php?user1=' + user1 + '&user2=' + user2);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**index.html**

```
<script>
(function(){
  getChatHistory('user1','user2', function(resp){
     alert(resp);
  });
})();
</script>
```

Comment: OK. Will try right know. Thanks a lot. The first option works but the second one... i don't really know how to do it. Could you show an example?

Comment: Consider providing an example of how to use a callback with `getChatHistory`, to clarify why you shouldn't return `response`. Good answer though.

Comment: @gabrielgarcia I've also added a simple example of how you can handle the response.

Comment: @gabrielgarcia no problem, if you are looking for a more robust/modern way to handle async systems I would suggest familiarizing yourself with the `Promise` module (if you haven't done so already). Good luck!

Comment: @gabrielgarcia that's the one. A useful pattern for chaining mulitple asynchronous requests, or just handling the results of a request in a clean manner.

Comment: After implementing it on my chat i've seen it is better to write the `onComplete(response)` between the `xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 4` to avoid executing the callback more times than needed.